# Is it possible to create read-only live USB stick for Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, live-usb

Is it possible to create bootable live USB stick with Ubuntu that does not allow writing anything to it, similar to live CD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, while creating live usb if you don't  allocate any `persistence storage`, no new data can be written and USB can be said as locked.

It may looks like the above statement is not true if you try to download / install any software or other things. Those are downloaded and also  accessible. **But that is only for current session**. Once you reboot the system all changes will be gone. The live cd/dvd also does the same.

Comment: jast to be sure, a live usb is safe from Virus, Worm,keyloggers or Trojan Horse?